# Is the Crookes tube with Maltese cross (cathode rays) safe in terms of produced X rays at 5-10kV DC (1–10mA) during, say, 15 seconds of work?

Tags: x-rays, fluorescence

I would like to get some information on the operational safety of this equipment. How much, approximately (just the order of magnitude) does the school Crookes tube with the Maltese cross, used to demonstrate cathode rays, produce X rays at 5-10kV DC (1–10mA) during, say, 10-15 seconds of work from a 1 meter distance? Is this safe to shortly demonstrate the cathode rays with these settings? I already know, that this device is able to generate X-rays even at 5kV, now I'm wondering how much.

Initially I wanted to power it from the Ruhmkorff inductor, but I have only a big one, able to deliver several tens of kilovolts. I found it unsafe. Instead, I want to use a small 5-10kV transformer with balast resistor, limiting the current to about 1-5mA, or use the Ruhmkorff with a very short spark gap (to limit the voltage this way), powered from a low-voltage source (about 4V).

My initial setting with 3kV / 5mA transformer did fire the tube (blue glow), but no green luminescence appeared. Probably also because it was AC. Now I will use an old TV HV rectifier and want to try a bit higher ratings, but, at the same time, I don't want to expose myself to significant X radiation. I know this was used in schools in '60-'70s, but then it was withdrawn from use for safety reasons.

Now I'm curious how much **unsafe** it is.

It won't be run for any audience, just for me, to see how it works. I won't look at the output directly - I will use a mirror, which reflects the visible spectrum, but lets the X-rays pass through it.